# Invalid podfile with new React Native project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

I just created a new React Native project, and when I try and run `pod install` in the `ios` directory I get this error:

```
Invalid `Podfile` file: cannot load such file -- ./scripts/autolinking
```

I didn't start the project with Expo, but it looks like my Podfile has this line at the top:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(`node --print "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"`), "scripts/autolinking")
```

Are there any known fixes? I'm not sure why Expo is being included in my project here.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Having the same issue